# Dynamically mapping JSON request to other JSON without POJO class

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I want to create a functionality in code when I get JSON request and convert the fields of this JSON to another one JSON object based on fields mapping in DB.
For example:
Request Json

```
{
    {
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": "value2",
    "data": {
        "param3": "value3"
    }
}
```

Table in DB:

```
param1 | newMappedParam1
param2 | newMappedParam2
param3 | newMappedParam3
```

New generated Json object:

```
 {
        {
        "newMappedParam1": "value1",
        "newMappedParam2": "value2",
        "data": {
            "newMappedParam3": "value3"
        }
    }
```

I can create POJO model object and then just to manipulate with this. But when the new parameter is added, I need also to update the POJO model and it requires to release a new version of application. This is not desired option.

I think on another approach like getting the JSON request , on the fly I convert to some JSONObject and then I map and build anew Json object. And when i'm required to add the new parameter , i just add the record in DB and no more new releases for this.

Do you think this approach is very good for this?
Thanks

Comment: For dynamic mapping your second approach will be a good option

Comment: Thanks, this is what only i think about this... May be some other approaches(if they exist that i don't know in Spring Boot/Java) can match to this challenge?